# Remove top shadow from the screen - Ubuntu Xfce

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, window-manager, xfwm4

I can't find anywhere how to remove shadow for the top edge of the screen.

The only thing that gave me something similar was setting the opacity of windows decoration to transparent in Window Manager Tweaks, but that also removes controls for minimizing and maximizing windows, and that's not what I want.

Here's a screenshot of what I would like to do, a picture is worth a thousand words :)

[image]

If it means anything, window manager is Xfwm4

Comment: Do you see the same shadow with another wallpaper or if you apply a plain light color as the background instead of a wallpaper?

Comment: @DKBose I do, I tried to change that wallpaper and it's always the same. Like I said when I set the opacity of window decorations to transparent that shadow disappear, but what also disappear are controls for windows like min, max, and close buttons and I would like to keep that visible

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu & xfce?

Comment: And do you have Cairo dock or something similar installed?

Comment: Anyway, see if https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077666/how-do-i-remove-this-horizontal-line-on-my-screen helps.

Comment: @DK Bose That solution might work if *show shadows under dock windows* was ticked. Maybe it isn't an X11 dock?

Comment: OP hasn't responded so …